# Pushing to github from a TeamCity agent

Tags: git, ssh, teamcity

I use a TeamCity build agent to build code. When I built it I change a file, commit it and want to push it back. I don't want to use my password in the Build Step's command line. So, I use the SSH Exec runner type. I made a key, uploaded the public one to github and the private one to TeamCity. I create the build step:
Authentification method: Uploaded key
Target: github.com
Username: git
Select key: id_rsa
Commands: git fetch origin master

And I get such error:

```
Permanently added 'github.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
  Executing commands:
eval “$(ssh-agent -s)”
on host [github.com]
  Invalid command: 'git fetch origin master'
    You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.
    Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the
    GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set.
  SSH exit-code 1
  Step checkout watchtower (SSH Exec) failed
```

I tried different commands, for example 'eval “$(ssh-agent -s)”', result is the same.
So, how can I fetch or push to github from the TeamCity agent?

Comment: Please show your URL for the `origin`. I suspect you use `git://` protocol. You can clone a repository using `git://` protocol but cannot push — `git://` protocol is read-only. Change the remote URL to `https://` or `ssh://` protocol.

Comment: I tried different variants: git fetch ssh://git@github.com/name.git branch; git fetch https://github.com/name.git branch. Nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues was in ssh auth error on the agent. When I copied rsa keys to /root/.ssh I could do in a "Command line" build step:
git clone -b test ssh://git@github.com/repo_name.git test
The root acount is used by the agent. I don't know why TeamCity doesn't use keys which I provied it in the build settings.

Answer (score 0):

If, as commented, you are using a `git://` URL, but cannot change it easily, you still can, on the TeamCity agent, add a:

```
git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf git://github.com/
```

Without having to modify your URLs, TeamCity would use SSH URL instead of `git://` ones.